# It does not work "onclick" with attr () from JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, onclick

I'm trying to add an "onclick" event with their respective function from js JQuery to an interactive table td I'm doing in another .php file, the problem is not executed in the place where I want to do it but if the same instruction is executed correctly within an AJAX request a few lines below, will show you the code:

This instruction is giving me the problem:

```
$(td).attr("onclick","agregar_pensum_etapa2 (this,'"+subject+"','"+level+"','"+stage+"');");
```

And this, the function I want to run with the "onclick"

```
function agregar_pensum_etapa2(td,subject,level,stage){

        $(document).ready(function(){
            // Capture variables.
            var id_periodo = $("#id_periodo").val();
            var id_asignatura = subject;
            var id_nivel = level;
            var id_etapa = stage;
            var id_mencion = null;
            if (level> 3) {
               id_mencion = 0;
            }

            // Modifiable column.
            var tr = $(td).parent();
            var index_td = $(td).index();

            // First field
            var valor_anterior = $(td).text();
            $(td).html("<img src =" images / save_64.png 'width = '16' height = '16 '> & nbsp; & nbsp; & nbsp;' + '<input value = "' + valor_anterior + '" type = "text" style = "width: 40px; border: 1px solid #aaa;" onkeypress = "return soloNumeros (event);" maxlength = "2"> ');
            $(td).removeAttr("onclick");
            $(td).find("input").focus();

            // Second field

            var valor_anterior_cs = $(tr).find("td:eq("+(index_td+1)+")").text();
            var checked_cs = "";
            if (valor_anterior_cs === "X"){checked_cs = "checked"}
            $ (tr) .find ("td: eq (" + (index_td + 1) + ")") html ("<input type = 'checkbox'" + checked_cs + ">").

            // Third field

            var valor_anterior_hum = $(tr).find("td:eq("+(index_td+2)+")").text();
            var checked_hum  = "";
            if(valor_anterior_hum === "X") {checked_hum = "checked"}
            $(tr).find("td:eq("+(index_td+2)+")").html("<input type = 'checkbox'"+checked_hum+">");

           / ************************************************* *********** /


            $(td).find("img").click(function(){

                var hora_asignatura  = $(td).find("input").val();

                var mencion_cs = "NO";
                if($(tr).find("td:eq("+(index_td+1)+")").find("input").is ("checked")){mencion_cs = "YES";}

                var mencion_hum = "NO";
                if($(tr).find("td:eq("+(index_td+2)+")").find("input").is("checked")){mencion_hum = "YES";}


                if(hora_asignatura === ""){

                   if(valor_anterior != ''){

                     $(td).html(valor_anterior);      
                     $(tr).find("td:eq("+index_td+1)+")").text(valor_anterior_cs);
                     $(tr).find("td:eq("+(index_td+2)+")").text(valor_anterior_hum);
                   }else{

                     $(td).html("");
                     $(tr).find("td:eq("+(index_td+1)+")").text("");
                     $(tr).find("td:eq("+(index_td+2)+")").text("");
                   }

                   \\// --> HERE IS NOT WORKING <-- \\//
                   $(td).attr("onclick","agregar_pensum_etapa2(this,'"+subject +"','"+level+"','"+stage+"');");
                }else if(hora_asignatura == "0"){

                   if(valor_anterior! = ''){

                      $(td).html(valor_anterior);
                      $(tr).find("td:eq("+(index_td+1)+")").text (valor_anterior_cs);
                      $(tr).find("td:eq("+(index_td+2)+")").text (valor_anterior_hum);
                   }else{

                      $(td).html("<img src =" images / diagonal.png 'height = '16' style = 'width: 15px ">");
                      $(tr).find("td:eq("+(index_td+1)+")").text("");
                      $(tr).find("td:eq("+(index_td+2)+")").text("");
                   }

                   \\// --> HERE IS NOT WORKING <-- \\//
                   $(td).attr("onclick","agregar_pensum_etapa2(this,'"+subject+"','"+level+ "','"+stage+"');");
                }else{

                    $.ajax({
                        async: true,
                        cache: false,
                        dataType: "html"
                        type: 'POST'
                        url: "../Controlador/CtrlPensum.php"
                        data: {

                            id_periodo: id_periodo,
                            id_asignatura: id_asignatura,
                            id_nivel: id_nivel,
                            id_etapa: id_etapa,
                            hora_asignatura: hora_asignatura,
                            mencion_cs: mencion_cs,
                            mencion_hum: mencion_hum,
                            id_mencion: id_mencion,
                            record: "register"
                        },
                        success: function (response) {
                            //alert (response);
                            if($.trim(answer) === "1") {

                               $(td).html(hora_asignatura);

                               var marcar_cs_x = "";
                               if(mencion_cs === "SI"){marcar_cs_x = "X";}

                               var marcar_hum_x = "";
                               if(mencion_hum === "SI"){marcar_hum_x = "X";}

                               $(tr).find("td:eq("+(index_td+1)+")").html (marcar_cs_x).
                               $(tr).find("td:eq("+(index_td+2)+")").html (marcar_hum_x).

                               \\// --> HERE IT WORKS <-- \\//
                               $(td).attr("onclick", "agregar_pensum_etapa2 (this,'"+subject+"','"+level+"','"+stage+"');");
                               cargarTablaResumen ();

                            } Else {
                                alert ("Error SQL statement is not executed." + response);
                            }
                            //tr.fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500);
                        },
                        beforeSend: function () {}
                        Error: function (objXMLHttpRequest) {}
                    });
                }
            });
        });
}
```

I try this:

```
$(td).click(function(){
     $(td).attr("onclick","agregar_pensum_etapa2 (this,'"+subject+"','"+level+ "','"+stage+"');");
});
```

And in the html it prints correctly but does not work, like he was not the "onclick" there. And the function if it works, I put the onclick to that function when I load the page and if it works, but when I click the td and give back to click to restore does not restore the onclick.

Comment: Provide us with the HTML or a fiddle, we can help you better that way.

Comment: Don't use inline JS—you can easily bind click events in jQuery without the need to muddle the markup with JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the `onclick` attribute, why not do use `.click()` again with closures? So your code would be something like...

```
$(td).click(function(){
    var td = this;
    $(td).click(function () {
         agregar_pensum_etapa2(td,subject,level,stage);
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you include a link to where it states that `.click(fn)` is deprecated?

Comment: you and me both @JohnS

Comment: Oooh buddy, thank you very much ... was already out of ideas. Spend a day and a half stuck with that problem. Thanks again.

By the way, you notice that the problem also came from "this"? testing and trying to remove the "this" of the attr ("onclick", "fn (this)") restored the "td" but the function was useless because it will not pass the td.

I had to add off () at the beginning of the function because every time it ran increased event handlers for the "td".

Comment: @Fred-ii- John S You're both super correct. I was thinking of `.live()`! I'll update my answer to reflect the truth. (even if I prefer `.on()`)

Comment: @ReedSpool and for some instinctive reason, I thought that's what you may have thought also, above `.live` and `.on`

Comment: Sorry @TheGrman I didn't read far enough into your code to understand the use of `this`. If you're using `.off()`, you probably want to be using `.on()` with namespaces. Check event namespaces out in the jQuery documentation.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it is so easy to confuse/forget the diff between "deprecated" and "not suggested for use" in daily life :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you write 
    $(Document)
Instead of    $(document)    with small letter "d".

Comment: no no, the letter "d" is capitalized by the text editor, the code that runs is the "d" and not the "D".